# How can I replace the placeholder with something to make the first condition always TRUE of this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I replace the placeholder with something to make the first condition always *TRUE* of this SQL statement?

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE field1 {placeholder} and field2 > 0;
```

`{placeholder}` = ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: you can use `1 = 1` ?

Comment: And why not removing it altogether?

Comment: @AlonEitan Because I dont know the field name. User inputs a SQL with placeholder so it would be more elegant to replace the placeholder instead of removing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Actually, if it will always be `true`, why do you need it? This sounds like it may be an XY Problem. Can you tell us what your flow is and your ultimate goal? There may be a better way to accomplish what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: What is the type of column?

Comment: @Shawn Under some cases I will replace the placeholder with something significant to fit the business logic, but the case I ask is that I need to ignore the condition of field1.

Comment: @SalmanA it can be any type and NULL value.

Comment: So you are going to build a dynamic SQL string here since you don't know the name of `field1` yet? I think I understand your intent, I'm just not sure this is the proper way to solve your issue. That's why I asked about your intended workflow.

Comment: This really sounds like 2 problems you're trying to solve here: 1) User doesn't supply a `field1`, so always be true ( so 1=1, `field1=field1` or just remove it) and 2) user supplies a `field` that you don't know the name for ( so probably dynamic SQL to build the field name to compare ). Correct?

Answer (score 5):

You could add comparison to itself:

```
SELECT fields
FROM table 
WHERE field1 <=> field1 and field2 > 0;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=aa58439b5ec68e8ecc448362f51b173a)**

*EDIT*:

> *If I dont know the field name of field1, are there any ways to accomplish?*

1) Remove entire condition

```
SELECT fields
FROM table 
WHERE field2 > 0;
```

2) Use `OR 1=1`

```
SELECT fields
FROM table
WHERE (field1 = <anything> OR 1=1) AND fields2 > 0;
```

Comment: If I dont know the field name of `field1`, are there any ways to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace it with the null-safe comparison operator: `<=> field1`.